# Ionic project create with package name

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a Ionic project. Ionic document specifies the command `ionic start myNewProject tabs`. How and where should I mention the package name?

Thank you

Comment: do you mean widget id? eg : `com.abc.sadsda`?

Comment: You don't need to mention package name.It creates the name itself which you can check in config.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can set the package name in your config.xml file..

```
<widget id="com.me_a_developer.myNewProject" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```